# Bifurcation Diagram stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm wondering how you know which branches are stable. For example taking $\alpha$ as the bifurcation parameter $$y'=\frac{y(1500-y)}{3200}-\alpha.$$

So I plot $\alpha=\frac{y(1500-y)}{3200}$ and flip the axes to get 
[image]

From here I'm not sure how to work out the stability of the branches. I know the bottom branch is the unstable one, just not sure of the method why. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given:

$$y'=\dfrac{y(1500-y)}{3200}-\alpha$$

We first want to find the critical points of $y' = 0$, yielding:

$$y' = \dfrac{y(1500-y)}{3200}-\alpha = 0 \rightarrow y_1 = 10 \left(75-\sqrt{5625-32 \alpha}~\right), y_2 = 10 \left(75 + \sqrt{5625-32 \alpha}~\right)$$

We then want to evaluate the sign of the derivative of $f(y) = \dfrac{y(1500-y)}{3200}-\alpha$ at each critical point. We have:

$$f'(y) = \dfrac{750-y}{1600}$$

At the first critical point, we have:

$$f'(y_1) = \dfrac{750-10 \left(75-\sqrt{5625-32 \alpha}~\right)}{1600}$$

A plot of this shows:

[image]

Notice how this is always positive (you should be able to prove this), hence is a **Source** (unstable).

At the second critical point, we have:

$$f'(y_2) = \dfrac{750-10 \left(\sqrt{5625-32 \alpha}+75~\right)}{1600} $$

A plot of this shows:

[image]

Notice how this is always negative (you should be able to prove this), hence is a **Sink** (stable).

We also have a common point, Node (neither stable nor unstable) at:

$$\alpha = \dfrac{5625}{32}, y = 750$$

If we draw the bifurcation diagram (red = unstable, green = stable, and the node where these two intersect as described above), we have:

[image]

Comment: This is the way I would have thought to do it, but is there a quicker way e.g. for an exam? This is a similar type of question I would expect to draw a bifurcation diagram for in an exam, but in the solutions the lecturer seems to go straight from the diagram to knowing the stability with a note saying stability follows from where $f(y)<0$ or $f(y)>0$ in the diagram, where $f(y)=y'$. Thanks for the response, I'll accept when I'm at uni tomorrow - I can't use my account there.

Comment: True, it's not much work - just thought I was missing some easy trick. Many thanks for the help once again.